# where is logger.getAppender (migrating from log4j to slf4j+log4j)

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, log4j2, slf4j-api

Existing code is setting up logger programmatically. Thats how it does it

```
public void init (String logFile, Logger logger){
    Validate.isTrue(logger.getAppender(APPENDER_NAME) == null, "Logger has configured project appender");

    //remaining code
}
```

now, i have changed `logger` object from `log4j` logger to `org.slf4j.Logger` and getting error that `getAppender` method doesn't exist. What should be the alternate here.

Comment: Why do you configure the logger programmatically? Also, I'm guessing that you're migrating from log4j1 to slf4j + log4j2 but can you please confirm if this is really the case?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that's not possible by using `slf4j` API.

`slf4j` is a logger facade API and exposes only high-level methods like `debug`, `trace`, etc.  It doesn't have notion of appenders, which is implementation detail of concrete underling logging, like `log4j`.

Excerpt from [SLF4J FAQ](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#when):

> SLF4J is only a facade, meaning that it does not provide a complete logging solution. Operations such as configuring appenders or setting logging levels cannot be performed with SLF4J. Thus, at some point in time, any non-trivial application will need to directly invoke the underlying logging system. In other words, complete independence from the API underlying logging system is not possible for a stand-alone application. Nevertheless, SLF4J reduces the impact of this dependence to near-painless levels.

The same is true for `log4j2` API as well.

What are the options:

1. Separate part of code, which will be coupled with `log4j` logger and do required configurations and validations there.
2. Another approach is to cast `slf4j` logger  to `log4j` after check:

   ```
   // log4j 1.x
   if (logger instanceof org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) {
      org.apache.log4j.Logger log4j = (org.apache.log4j.Logger) logger;
      // access to log4j.getAppender("APPENDER_NAME");
   }
   ```